# Include many-to-many field in admin page for reverse related model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

For the model below I want to create an admin page where I directly can edit the `user_permissions` for the related `django_user`. How would I do that?

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    django_user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

This is what I have so far, but this is read only (and, in my opinion, a bit hacky):

```
# admin.py

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('user_permissions',)

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user_form = UserForm(instance=self.instance and self.instance.django_user, prefix=self.prefix)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
    change_form_template = 'my_model_change_form.html'

# my_model_change_form.html

{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}


{% block field_sets %}
    {% for fieldset in adminform %}
        {% include "admin/includes/fieldset.html" %}
    {% endfor %}
    <form>{{ adminform.form.user_form }}</form>
{% endblock %}
```